# Multi-stage Docker for development, testing, staging and production

Tags: python, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028097/use-multi-stage-docker-files-for-outputting-multiple-images), I have another one about what's the correct order.

This

```
FROM <some image> AS base
...
FROM base AS test
...
FROM test AS staging
...
FROM staging AS prod
```

or this

```
FROM <some image> AS base
...
FROM base AS prod
...
FROM base AS staging
...
FROM base AS test
...
```

My concern is that, in the first option, I will have all my test tools in production, which is something I don't want, and in the second, this will not happen, but I can test if `prod` is working because I never tested it (maybe because packages were missing).

Is there some kind of consensus on which is the right one?

**Extra**: I work with Python. Is there a better choice for Python that maybe doesn't apply on a more general case?

**Update**: I use PostGIS for production but wanted to use `libsqlite3-mod-spatialite` for development because is lighter and I probably won't the kind of problems that make you choose PostGIS for production.

Comment: Why not uninstall the test tools in the first option?

Comment: I wouldn't install the test tools in Docker at all; make them available in your host development and/or CI environment.  Use the same Docker image in all environments, and make sure the thing you're running in production is exactly the same thing you tested.

Comment: @MadWombat A concrete example: I use PostGIS on production but for testing I use `libsqlite3-mod-spatialite`, which is ligher that PostGIS. This is one of my test tools that I don't want it on production

Comment: If that is the case I am not sure what the problem is. You are not OK with your "scenario #2" even though the difference between prod and test in that one is a bunch of test tools, but you are OK with testing on a completely different set of dependencies. If your production runs PostgreSQL, but you are testing on SQLite, you are not really testing your production anyway.

Comment: I'm not OK with any of them, for the exact same reason you mentioned: I'm not testing production the right way. My question is if there is a best way to do this of if this is a trade off and there is no best answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the first approach is not recommended for Production. You should not keep on increasing the attack surface by simply adding on to the base -> test->stage->Production.
You rightly mentioned, the unnecessary software from test stage should be stripped down in Production.

I believe what you did in test stage is verify you application using tools. Now if you essentially are using the same app in production build with all your dependencies bundled along with, the app should work. Testing you final production app should be done after the build and before deployment now. Which I think is out of scope of Production container build.

I hope this makes sense..?